# Embed a .net application inside Microsoft Dynamic CRM

Tags: .net, dynamic, crm, connector

We have created a .net application for chatbot services. we want to add that application inside dynamic CRM as a button like the chat provided by ms crm.

How is it possible? Are any samples available?

I searched over internet but didn't receive any idea